# Error using Html.Action MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this view to make a menu where I use a @Html.Action:

```
@model SGP.Models.Turma

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Menu";
}

...
@Html.Action("AvaliacaoLista", "Turma", new { id = Model.TurmaId })
```

The view in the Html.Action:

```
@model  List<SGP.Models.PessoaModel2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Numero</th>

            @foreach (String s in ViewBag.Componentes)
            {
                <th>@s</th>
            }

            <th>Nota Final</th>
        </tr>

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].turmaId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].userid)
                <td>@Model[i].nome</td>
                <td>@Model[i].num</td>

                @for (int a = 0; a < Model[i].am.Count; a++)
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].am[a].AvaliacaoId)
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model[i].am[a].nota)</td>
                }
                <td>@Model[i].notafinal</td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
}
```

This is what it shows in the view:
[image: Image with names omitted]
Can someone tell me why is it doing this? Or should I use other way to make that table appear in the menu instead of using Html.Action?
Thanks
(I only want to show the table and not repeat the header)

Comment: What is the exact error??

Comment: _"Can someone tell me why is it doing this?"_ - what is "this", exactly?

Comment: @PowerStar I only want to show the table and not repeat the "Software Gestão Pedagógica", "Bem vindo, ProfTeste"

Comment: You got answer below.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You getting your logo twice becouse your View have it also (which  you call with `Html.Action`) so just set your subView `Layout` to `null`:

```
@model  List<SGP.Models.PessoaModel2>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
// your other stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahh ok I can see what your problem is. You "heading" is repeating itself.

The simplest way to solve this is to add:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

To any View that you want to render only the HTML within. This way it will not render layout pages, that are by default, rendered with the views.